# Android IME how to commit text to an added EditText inside the same InputView?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, ime

I have made an IME Keyboard for Android which still requires an in-view EditText to search through Emojis.

Even when the EditText shows a blinking cursor, I am unable to type into it!

Google's GBoard has that, & many other keyboards, let you filter Emojis, via typing in such a search box!

[Image showing what I am trying to do!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfoMU.jpg)

I've tried using InputConnection#setImeConsumesInput(true) but that isn't availabe inside IME Service class itself!

I've tried EditText#requestFocsus() as well! Still failed to type into it!